# How to set line width on Graphics?

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to draw a line two pixels wide.  How can I do this?

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question.  What is this for?  How tall?  etc.

Comment: Ok, For example on Android : paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
This method sets line width. In this case, line width is 3 pixels. 
I am searching just like this method on BlackBerry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method to set the width of your line.  You do have two options though:

1) If your line is horizontal/vertical, then you can use fillRect to draw your lines.

2) You can draw multiple lines offset by a pixel in the x or y direction to make the appearance of a thicker line.

They may not be ideal, but they get the job done.

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much the only way on Blackberry. Its pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

There is no methods to set the width for a line. But if you want you can draw like below code. I don't think this is correct way. But it will help you.

```
Graphics c = new Graphics();
c.drawLine(5, 20, width-10, 20);
c.drawLine(5, 21, width-10, 20);
```